# How Do I get the author's page id?

Tags: permalinks, url-rewriting

I need to assign comments a user makes to the author's page where the user is posting the comment. So, I need to get the author's page id.

I have already tried functions like: `url_to_postid()` and `get_page_by_path()` with no success.

I am using a custom permalink structure for author pages: `http://sitename.com/USERNAME`

Is there a way I can accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you need [`get_author_posts_url()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_author_posts_url) which "Gets the URL of the author page for the author with a given ID." If you have set the custom permalink correctly it should work.

If you really are looking for actual page IDs, ***there is no page ID for an author archive page***. Those pages are dynamically generated and are not "posts", "pages", or any other post type. They are not built to support comments. You are going to have to cook up your own system for that.

Comment: `get_author_posts_url()` works for getting the url, but I need the page id of that url so I can attach comments to it. I can get the ids of posts and other pages without a problem; however, I am not able to get the ids of authors' pages. I do think that the problem resides in the set up of the permalink structure I have, as you just said, but I have no idea on how to find out the problem. The alternative I am thinking of is to create a new page for every user and attach the comments to those. I could even make a custom post type just for it to have more control over it. What do you think?

Comment: ***There is no page ID for an author archive page.*** Those pages are dynamically generated and are not "posts", "pages", or any other post type. They are not built to support comments. You are going to have to cook up your own system for that.

Comment: Great! Thanks. I was not sure about this. Now, I know what to do. Please update your answer so I can select it.

Comment: Specifically, they are archives that list posts, e.g. posts of type 'page'. Archives are just lists, hence asking for their post ID is a nonsensical question once you understand how they work. However, you could ask for the authors User ID, and store data in the users meta, but you can't comment on an archive or a user themselves